# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerBean when using SimpleTriggerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to migrate a project from spring 2.5.6 and java 6 to spring 4.2.3 and java 8, running on a wildfly 9 server. I have updated the SimpleTriggerBean references to SimpleTriggerFactoryBean according to discussions and examples (eg. http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/)

However, when I run the application I receive the following error;

> WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invalSvc' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/resources/spring/spring-cfg.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'changeHelper' while setting bean property 'changeHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'changeHelper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/resources/spring/spring-cfg.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'invalRpcHelper' while setting bean property 'invalRpcHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invalRpcHelper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/resources/spring/spring-cfg.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerBean

The code I'm running does not have any visual references to SimpeTriggerBean and I am unable to figure out why this happens. SimpleTriggerFactoryBean should work in both Quartz 1.x and 2.x.

Spring xml data;

```
<bean name="retryHandlerImpl" class="com.myproject.code.rpc.vscall.RetryHandlerImpl">
    <property name="passwordManager" ref="passwordManager" />
    <property name="signal" ref="signal" /> 
    <property name="handleToSTB" ref="fileTrigger" />  
    <property name="serverLoader" ref="serverLoader" />
    <property name="serializeHelper" ref="serializeHelper" /> 
</bean>

<bean name="invalRpcHelper" class="com.myproject.code.rpc.calls.InvalRpcHelperImpl">
    <property name="rpcHelper" ref="retryHandlerImpl" />
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean name="inputController"
    class="com.myproject.code.control.InputController">
        <property name="partnerDao" ref="partnerDao" />
        <property name="passwordManager" ref="passwordManager" />
        <property name="appData" ref="appData" />
        <property name="signal" ref="signal" />
        <property name="fileHelper" ref="fileHelper" />
</bean>


    <!--  Non Quartz Job Scheduling -->
<bean id="scheduleFileReaderJob"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="inputController"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="startFrontEndProcesses" >

    </property>

    <!--  dont want two instances of reader bean to run -->
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="fileTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduleFileReaderJob" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="${FILE_POLL_INTERVAL}" />
</bean>
```

The relevant cut out of RetryHandlerImpl;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
/* upgrading from spring 2.5.4 */
//import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean;
/* to */
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean;

// -> a lot of project class imports go here

public class RetryHandlerImpl extends RpcHelperImpl {

    private static PasswordManager passwordManager;

    private static Signal signal;

    private static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean handleToSTB;

    private static ServerLoader serverLoader;

    private static SerializeHelper serializeHelper;

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RetryHandlerImpl.class
            .getName());

    private static int noOfRetries = 0;

    private static final int MAX_RETRIES;

    private static final int HIBERNATE_TIME_IN_MINUTES;

    static {
        try {
            MAX_RETRIES = Integer.parseInt(VMProps.get(CommonCons.MAX_RETRIES));
            HIBERNATE_TIME_IN_MINUTES = Integer.parseInt(VMProps
                    .get(VMCons.HIBERNATE_TIME_IN_MINUTES));
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            throw new AppException(CommonCons.APP_INIT_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This code sets the application to hibernate.
     * 
     * The second argument:
     * 
     * If it is true, it means that the same server must be used for processing
     * as already a call has gone to this server
     * 
     * If it is false, then it starts trying from the first server in the list
     * of serverLoader.servers
     * 
     */
    private void setAppToHibernateMode(boolean callNotPlaced,
            Server currentServer) {

        makeItEasyForUsByLogging(log, callNotPlaced, currentServer);

        // Select the hibernate time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, HIBERNATE_TIME_IN_MINUTES);
        Date date = c.getTime();
        handleToSTB.setStartTime(date);

        if (callNotPlaced) {
            log.info("Since callNotPlaced is " + callNotPlaced
                    + " setting currentServer to null ");
            signal.setCurrentServer(null);
        }

        serializeHelper.serializeSignal(signal);

        // There shall be no more retries,
        // while loop shall exit automatically,
        // Instead we throw the error.
        throw new VSException(ErrCons.APP_HIBERNATE);

    }

    public void setSignal(Signal sig) {
        signal = sig;
    }

    public void setHandleToSTB(SimpleTriggerFactoryBean handleToST) {
        this.handleToSTB = handleToST;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServerLoader(ServerLoader serverLoad) {
        this.serverLoader = serverLoad;
    }

    public void setSerializeHelper(SerializeHelper serializeHelper) {
        this.serializeHelper = serializeHelper;
    }

    private void logboth(String message) {
        log.error(message);
        Metrics.writeln(message);
    }
}
```

the POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Spring version utility -->
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-ws.version>2.2.4.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>    

</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>      
    </pluginManagement> 
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- I have tested with multiple versions of quartz and without it, but to no avail.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>quartz</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.archiva.redback.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE_4</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>  
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpg-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>toplink.essentials</groupId>
        <artifactId>toplink-essentials</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-60f</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>ws-commons-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>logkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>  
</project>
```

I have tested around with multiple versions of spring and quartz.

If I remove all references from and to retryHandlerImpl (including the inputController, scheduleFileReaderJob and fileTrigger) the exception is still thrown.

```
<bean name="retryHandlerImpl" class="com.myproject.code.rpc.vscall.RetryHandlerImpl">
/*
    <property name="passwordManager" ref="passwordManager" />
    <property name="signal" ref="signal" /> 
    <property name="handleToSTB" ref="fileTrigger" />  
    <property name="serverLoader" ref="serverLoader" />
    <property name="serializeHelper" ref="serializeHelper" /> 
*/
</bean>

<bean name="invalRpcHelper" class="com.myproject.code.rpc.calls.InvalRpcHelperImpl">
    //<property name="rpcHelper" ref="retryHandlerImpl" />
</bean>
```

Any ideas or thoughts on why there is this dependency, or which versions of which library that would be the magic combination, would be most welcome.

Best regards,

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError usually means that a class is missing at runtime. As you run this code in a container check which version of the jars are included in the container. Maybe something is loaded from the container jars and not from app.

Comment: @AndrásTóth You are correct; In the process of upgrading from ant to maven a mistake was made and the compiled version of the java classes where placed inside the WEB-INF directory. This led to some discrete conflicts at runtime. Only by not loading the involved classes at all would let the application to circumvent the problem, hence the suspect symptoms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
 In the process of upgrading from ant to maven a mistake was made and the compiled version of the classes where placed inside the WEB-INF directory.

This led to some discrete conflicts at runtime. Only by not loading the involved classes at all would let the application to circumvent the problem, hence the suspect symptoms.

Removing the folder from WEB-INF solved the problem.